# Getting "No results found" using `sfdx force:source:pull` for custom metadata records

Tags: salesforcedx

I am using the `Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment()` method to deploy some custom metadata records into my org.

This works fine, but when I then try to pull those records into my local repo using:

`sfdx force:source:pull`

I get a `No results found` message.

If I use `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomMetadata`, then the custom metadata records are retrieved as expected.

However, I think that `sfdx force:source:pull` should work. Does anyone know why it isn't working?

*Further note:* If I edit one of the custom metadata records manually in Salesforce, it then become visible to the `sfdx force:source:pull` command.

Comment: I believe source:pull only pulls records that have changed from what you have locally. So if you're just deploying then trying to pull with no changes, you will get no results: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metadata that is deployed via the API, including `force:source:deploy` or `Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment`, is not source-tracked. Only changes made in the Scratch Org in Setup/Developer Console will be logged for `force:source:pull`. Instead, use `force:source:retrieve`.

Comment: @sfdxfox Thanks very much for the info.